Issue Screen with Navigator bottom tabs into my app React Native
I try to make different screens after the client connects to the App. Connecting to Firebase works without a hitch. I can see the new user in my database. However, every time I try to put a navigator and a Tab.Screens in the AuthenticatedScreen const, I get nothing.
However, when I put a simple View, it works.
the code :
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signOut, signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { UserProvider, useUser } from './UserContext';
import AuthScreen from './AuthScreen';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import Homescreen from './screens/Homescreen';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Utilisation de initializeAuth avec AsyncStorage
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
});

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const AuthenticatedScreen = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Homescreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const { user, setUser } = useUser();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [auth]);

  const handleAuthentication = async () => {
    try {
      if (user) {
        await signOut(auth);
      } else {
        if (isLogin) {
          await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        } else {
          await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Authentication error:', error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      {user ? (
        <AuthenticatedScreen />
      ) : (
        <AuthScreen
          email={email}
          setEmail={setEmail}
          password={password}
          setPassword={setPassword}
          isLogin={isLogin}
          setIsLogin={setIsLogin}
          handleAuthentication={handleAuthentication}
        />
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
});

export default () => (
  <UserProvider>
    <App />
  </UserProvider>
);


I found an answer. The issue is the Scroll View. it seems to interfere with React Navigator
Remove this :
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      {user ? (
        <AuthenticatedScreen />
      ) : (
        <AuthScreen
          email={email}
          setEmail={setEmail}
          password={password}
          setPassword={setPassword}
          isLogin={isLogin}
          setIsLogin={setIsLogin}
          handleAuthentication={handleAuthentication}
        />
      )}
    </ScrollView>

and change by :
if (user) {
    return <AuthenticatedScreen />
  }

  return (
    <AuthScreen
      email={email}
      setEmail={setEmail}
      password={password}
      setPassword={setPassword}
      isLogin={isLogin}
      setIsLogin={setIsLogin}
      handleAuthentication={handleAuthentication}
    />
  );

After that the final code is :
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signOut, signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
import { UserProvider, useUser } from './UserContext';
import AuthScreen from './AuthScreen';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import Homescreen from './screens/Homescreen';
import Calendar from './screens/Calendar';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Utilisation de initializeAuth avec AsyncStorage
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
});



const AuthenticatedScreen = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      await signOut(auth);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Logout error:', error.message);
    }
  };
   return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Homescreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Calendar" component={Calendar} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const { user, setUser } = useUser();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [auth]);

  const handleAuthentication = async () => {
    try {
      if (user) {
        await signOut(auth);
      } else {
        if (isLogin) {
          await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        } else {
          await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Authentication error:', error.message);
    }
  };

  if (user) {
    return <AuthenticatedScreen />
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AuthScreen
      email={email}
      setEmail={setEmail}
      password={password}
      setPassword={setPassword}
      isLogin={isLogin}
      setIsLogin={setIsLogin}
      handleAuthentication={handleAuthentication}
    />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
});

export default () => (
  <UserProvider>
    <App />
  </UserProvider>
);

